# Red5: logging for external library

Tags: logging, red5, slf4j

Given: Red5 0.8.RC3, application (.war) that uses a library (.jar).

The application uses slf4j for logging, all loggers are instantiated as follows:

```
private static Logger log = Red5LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class, "webcall"); //"webcall" is a context name
```

Configuration file for logging: logback-webcall.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

<contextName>webcall</contextName>

<jmxConfigurator contextName="webcall" />

<appender name="WEBCALL" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <File>/var/log/lx/webcall.log</File>
    <Append>false</Append>
    <Encoding>UTF-8</Encoding>
    <BufferedIO>false</BufferedIO>
    <ImmediateFlush>true</ImmediateFlush>
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
        <Pattern>
            %date [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n
        </Pattern>
    </layout>
</appender>
<root>
    <level value="DEBUG" /> 
    <appender-ref ref="WEBCALL" />
</root>
</configuration>
```

That one works for all loggers, that are instantiated as above. But in the **library** (which has no clue about Red5LoggerFactory and the contexts), the loggers are instantiated like this:

```
private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyLibraryClass.class); //org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
```

And they do not work.

Question: how to configure logging inside the library for Red5 server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to configure logging in red5/conf/logback.xml